# Viewing the metalsmith pipeline JSON

Tags: json, metalsmith

Metalsmith has an inbuilt way of displaying the pipeline contents, namely by using a simple function like:

```
    function(files, ms, done) {
        console.log('Files: ');
        console.log(files);
        console.log();
        console.log('Metalsmith ');
        console.log(ms);
        done();
    }
```

Or with [metalsmith-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metalsmith-logger)

```
logger(['title', 'tags', 'contents')
```

However in both cases I get the output as `[object Object]` and I require the full output. (i.e what I might get with JSON.stringify)

Even more so though, I wonder if there's any way to get a nicely formatted output of the pipe and contents after each transform, like one gets using gatsbyjs and graphQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [metalsmith-debug-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metalsmith-debug-ui) help? Nicely formatted React tool…

Comment: It seems perfect but doesn't work yet with gulp-metalsmith

Answer (score 1):

You can print out the object contents by using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to wrap the `files` and `ms` like this `JSON.stringify(files,null,3)` where `3` is the depth number of the object